# Mi interfaz no muestra los títulos de las columnas de un JTable pero sí los datos que lleva

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Estoy creando una interfaz sencilla en java y quiero agregar una tabla con 5 columnas. Una vez ejecutando el programa no muestra los títulos de las columnas sino solo los datos; también estoy posicionando los componentes con el método `setBounds()` así que es necesario para posicionar mi tabla de la manera que deseo. Aquí presento el código necesario descartando los otros componentes que ya he colocado pues no son de relevancia para este problema.

```
public class Interfaz{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame ventana = new JFrame("Interfaz");
        ventana.setLayout(null);
        ventana.setBounds(100,15,800,800);//posicion de la ventana
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//coloca la pantalla en medio 

        String[] titulos = {"Operación", "Argumento 1", "Argumento 2", "Resultado"};
        Object[][] datos = {{"Suma", 1, 2, 3},{"Resta", 1, 2, 3}};
        JTable cuadruplos = new JTable(datos, titulos);
        cuadruplos.setBounds(100, 250, 350, 350);
        ventana.add(cuadruplos);
        ventana.setVisible(true);//hace la ventana visible
    }//Cierre main
}//cierre de la clase principal
```

[image: Aquí muestro el resultado de como aparece mi tabla]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ahí explico que el problema es en la tabla, el código supuestamente está bien, pero al ejecutar mi programa la tabla no muestra los títulos de las columnas que asigné sino solo los datos tal como se ve en la imagen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias por incluir un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable. :-)

Hace tiempo que no trabajo con Swing, pero parece que [un JTable necesita de un JScrollPane para mostrar su cabecera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19066009/2553194)

Añadiendo ese elemento ya aparece

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestJTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame ventana = new JFrame("Interfaz");
    ventana.setLayout(null);
    ventana.setBounds(100,15,800,800);//posicion de la ventana
    ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//coloca la pantalla en medio

    String[] titulos = {"Operación", "Argumento 1", "Argumento 2", "Resultado"};
    Object[][] datos = {{"Suma", 1, 2, 3},{"Resta", 1, 2, 3}};
    JTable cuadruplos = new JTable(datos, titulos);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(cuadruplos);
    scrollPane.setBounds(100, 250, 350, 350);

    ventana.add(scrollPane);
    ventana.setVisible(true); //hace la ventana visible
}
}
```

[image: JFrame con JTable mostrando cabecera]

Comment: Me ayudó perfectamente que amable de su parte tomarse el tiempo para responder e incluso para hacerlo en su propia área de trabajo, quisiera saber si puede ayudarme a como agregar filas después de eso, más abajo de mi código tengo que agregar unos datos a la tabla, pero no pude lograr ingresarlos

Comment: @DiegoJimenez No sé lo que has intentado, como te decía no trabajo con Swing desde hace tiempo. [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3549341/2553194) tienes un ejemplo de añadir una fila nueva a una tabla. Yo te recomendaria que siguieras algún tutorial de Oracle sobre JTable. Si no te sale plantea una pregunta nueva y no te olvides de añadir el código que permita reproducir tu ejemplo

Comment: Lee [este](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) detenidamente y practica con sus ejemplos